# get the count my tag appearing in mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT det.tag_id,det.category_id,det.subcategory_id,det.event_id,dt.tag_name 
FROM `do_experience_tags` det
INNER JOIN `do_category` dc ON (det.subcategory_id=dc.`category_id` AND dc.is_master_category=1)
INNER JOIN do_tags dt ON (det.tag_id=dt.tag_id)

tagid   catid       subcatid   event_id     tag_name
174      4           25         2           #music
174      4           25         1           #music
```

How to get the count of the same tag name in new column

Answer (score 2):

Use `count` function:

```
SELECT det.tag_id, count(*) 
  FROM `do_experience_tags` det
  INNER JOIN `do_category` dc ON    
  (det.subcategory_id=dc.`category_id` AND     
  dc.is_master_category=1)
  INNER JOIN do_tags dt ON (det.tag_id=dt.tag_id)
 GROUP BY det.tag_id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show `count` to each row then you can do like below

```
select t1.id,t1.detail,
(select count(*) from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id =t2.id) as count
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.id =t2.id
```

use group by if you want to group values